# How to download data from previous stopped point?

Tags: java, android, web-services

In my application I am downloading data from the remote server. My Data's size is 289 MB. While downloading the data it happens many times that download stops in between and it starts download from the beginning. Now I want to implement such a download logic that will resume the download of data from the previous point.

Comment: What is the size of your data ?

Comment: size of data is 289 MB

Comment: That is a huge data i think. is it everytimer or one time only ?

Comment: okey, so is it one time URL call or you are calling more than one url one by one ?

Comment: it is one time url call

Comment: First of all make change in your webservice call, and instead of one URL call make multiple, because it would be very tedious job to download 289MB in one call, there may be lot of changes to get network single lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle HTTP request header called "Range" which tells which bytes you want. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving